# Facebook Automatically Logged Events of In-App Purchases not working on Android using flutter package facebook_app_events

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, in-app-purchase

Show app install and app active events on facebook events manager but nothing show when in-app purchases occur.

##### Steps To Reproduce

- Complete follow https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android
- Go to https://business.facebook.com/events_manager2/list/app/.......... . Then go to Test events tab.

###### Flutter Doctor command result

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 1.24.0-10.2.pre, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale en-PK)
    • Flutter version 1.24.0-10.2.pre at /Users/mapple.pk/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 022b333a08 (1 year, 1 month ago), 2020-11-18 11:35:09 -0800
    • Engine revision 07c1eed46b
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-29.10.beta)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mapple.pk/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/mapple.pk/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.2.1, Build version 13C100
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 13 (mobile) • 5098970B-881C-41AA-A2A9-DAA5EF67DAB7 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2
      (simulator)

• No issues found!
```